# How to go to specific native view controller from react-native code?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native-ios

I'm a newbie in react-native. I'm adding one feature in react-native to an existing swift application. I presented the `RCTRootview` from my native view controller. From there when user clicks on back button I have to go to Homepage which is written in swift. How do I communicate from react-native to native application code. Can someone please help me with this scenerio. I stuck at this point from last 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar issue and any help would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Native iOS - How can I navigate to a non-React-Native view (native iOS view controller) from a React-Native view with a button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741903/react-native-ios-how-can-i-navigate-to-a-non-react-native-view-native-ios-vie)

Comment: Hey @darkheartfelt Did you see that date when he answered from the link you shared? I answered this first. Then how come this became duplicate? The link you shared should be the duplicate of this?

Answer (score -3):

Yes. I found out the answer for this. It is all possible with **RCTBridgeModule**. This piece of code illustrate how to do that.

```
#import "CalendarManager.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation CalendarManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}
```

Now, from your JavaScript file you can call the method like this:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var CalendarManager = NativeModules.CalendarManager;
CalendarManager.addEvent('Birthday Party', '4 Privet Drive, Surrey');
```

Please follow the below [official link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) about the concept and how to do it.