# How can i create a react-native module with storyboard

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have received a sdk with a storyboard and multiple view controllers.
In my react-native module I want to expose a method that will transition to this storyboard and the get the result back. 
I have tried to follow this answer: 
[React-Native iOS - How can I navigate to a non-React-Native view (native iOS view controller) from a React-Native view with a button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741903/react-native-ios-how-can-i-navigate-to-a-non-react-native-view-native-ios-vie)

I have also tried this code (but we don't have access to the navigationController):

```
- (void)openStoryBoard{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NAME_OF_THE_STORYBOARD" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
}
```

in Android i have just called StartActivityForResult but i couldn't figure it out in ios.

any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Could you find a way to do it? Currently facing the same problem.

Comment: Could you add the full code or code of the flow that you want to do?