# How to open existing ViewController in swift from react native page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I am new to react native. I am adding react native in my existing iOS app which is partially in Objective C and Swift. I have added Native Module support, bridging in existing app. I don't know how to open a existing `ViewController` in swift from React Native Page.

I have gone through below link:
[How to go to specific native view controller from react-native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799601/how-to-go-to-specific-native-view-controller-from-react-native-code)

But don't know how to present or instantiate `ViewController` using `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD`, `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE`. Like in Android using `@ReactMethod` I can easily start new Activity from react native button click. Please help me with how can I open `ViewController` from react native page.

Comment: Have u got this working ? Are you able to open the Native view controller from react native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007680/4189507 ?

I was manage to do this in my application. It took me a few weeks to fully integrate react-native with native iOS and android (passing data, events etc. between them).

My current flow:

- running iOS native app with button "go to React-Native app"
- click on that button will open new Controller with react-native application.
- there is a button "go back" which simply closing the "react-native controller".

You can call native swift / objective-c methods from react-native using RCT_EXPORT_METHOD.

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for.